# ES6 classes, two sliders on same page with same selector class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I'm re-factoring a script in which I'm building a slider.  In one and the same page, I want to be able to display two sliders with the same class to select them (.slider). I manage to initialize both sliders, but only the second one on the page works. And when I click on the arrows in the first slider, it acts on the second slider on the page...
Thanks for all !

JS

```
export default class Slider {
    sliders: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> | null = null;
    slides!: HTMLElement;
    current: Element | undefined;
    caption!: HTMLElement;
    prev: Element | undefined;
    next: Element | undefined;

    constructor() {
        this.sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

        if (this.sliders.length) {
            this.sliders.forEach((slider: HTMLElement) => {
                this.slides = slider.querySelector(
                    '.slider__inner'
                ) as HTMLElement;
                let prevButton = slider.querySelector(
                    '.slider__controls-prev'
                ) as HTMLSpanElement;
                let nextButton = slider.querySelector(
                    '.slider__controls-next'
                ) as HTMLSpanElement;

                prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.move('prev'));
                nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.move());
                console.log(prevButton, nextButton);

                this.init(slider);
                this.applyClasses();
                this.setCaption();
            });
        }       
    }

    init(slider: HTMLElement): void {
        this.current =
            slider.querySelector('.slider__item-current') ||
            (this.slides.firstElementChild as HTMLLIElement);
        this.caption = slider.querySelector(
            '.slider__item-caption'
        ) as HTMLElement;
        this.prev =
            this.current.previousElementSibling ||
            (this.slides.lastElementChild as HTMLLIElement);
        this.next =
            this.current.nextElementSibling ||
            (this.slides.firstElementChild as HTMLLIElement);
    }

    applyClasses(): void {
        this.current?.classList.add('slider__item-current');
        this.prev?.classList.add('slider__item-prev');
        this.next?.classList.add('slider__item-next');
    }

    setCaption(): void {
        this.caption.textContent = this.current?.querySelector('figcaption')?.textContent;
    }

    move(direction?: string): void {
        const classesToRemove: string[] = [
            'slider__item-prev',
            'slider__item-current',
            'slider__item-next',
        ];
        this.prev?.classList.remove(...classesToRemove);
        this.current?.classList.remove(...classesToRemove);
        this.next?.classList.remove(...classesToRemove);

        if (direction === 'prev') {
            [this.prev, this.current, this.next] = [
                this.prev?.previousElementSibling ||
                    (this.slides.lastElementChild as HTMLElement),
                this.prev,
                this.current,
            ];
        } else {
            [this.prev, this.current, this.next] = [
                this.current,
                this.next,
                this.next?.nextElementSibling ||
                    (this.slides.firstElementChild as HTMLElement),
            ];
        }

        this.applyClasses();
        this.setCaption();
    }
}
```

HTML (smarty template)

```
<div class="slider">
            <div class="slider__wrapper">
                <ul class="slider__inner">
                    {{foreach from=$element.diaporama.images item="diapo"}}
                        <li class="slider__item">
                            <figure>
                                {{if $diapo.texte != ""}}
                                    {{assign var=alt value=$diapo.texte|html}}
                                {{/if}}
                                {{if $diapo.author != ""}}
                                    {{assign var=auteur value=$diapo.author|html}}
                                    {{assign var=alt value="`$alt` ©`$auteur`"}}
                                {{/if}}
                                <img loading="lazy" 
                                srcset="{{$diapo.url|image_bunny:cw480}} 480w,
                                        {{$diapo.url|image_bunny:cw600}} 600w,
                                        {{$diapo.url|image_bunny:cw1204}} 1204w"
                                sizes="(min-width: 767px) 600px,
                                    (min-width: 1184px) 1204px,
                                    480px" 
                                src="{{$diapo.url|image_bunny:cw480}}" alt="{{$alt|utf2asc|html_entity_decode|html}}">
                                <figcaption>
                                    {{if $diapo.texte != ""}}
                                        {{$diapo.texte|replace:"<p>":""|replace:"</p>":""}}
                                    {{else}}
                                        {{$diapo.titre|replace:"<p>":""|replace:"</p>":""}}
                                    {{/if}}
                                    {{if $auteur != ""}}
                                        <span>&copy {{$auteur}}</span>
                                    {{/if}}
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </li>
                    {{/foreach}}
                </ul>
                <div class="slider__controls">
                    <span class="slider__controls-prev picto-chevron"></span>
                    <span class="slider__controls-next picto-chevron"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item-caption"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would expect a class called `Slider` to be [responsible for **one single** slider per instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). It should not deal with all sliders on the page. It should be instantiated multiple times if there are multiple sliders.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple logic error in your constructor. Your `forEach()` loop runs the first time and sets a bunch of `this.<blablabla>` fields and runs some more methods that set more `this` stuff for the first slider right? But once that loop runs for a second time, it just reassigns all of those things using the second slider. For example, when it runs `init()`, `this.current` just gets changed to the second slider's `querySelector('.slider__item-current')`, so the first slider is left without one.

You just need to find a way to set everything *without* having the sliders' data overwrite each other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @NkemdiAnyiam 
I'm trying to isolate my values independently of each other but I can't figure out how to do it....